# Cannot fine 'logger' in scope despite importing all the packages

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-authentication

So I'll keep this short. I imported all the packages just fine and the app was working just fine until I started with the Firebase Auth stuff. I'm getting the following error:  "Cannot find 'logger' in scope". I have all the packages imported as shown in the image. Would appreciate any recommendation. Thanks! [image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import OSLog
```

That's it. You just needed to know the right framework.

Then you need to create an instance.

```
let logger = Logger()
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to do `import OSLog` at the top of the file and then write the actual log statement like this: `Logger.info(tag: "myTag", message: "myMessage")`